# How to fix "RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate()" - Content-Security-Policy

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webassembly, content-security-policy, quasar

I'm trying to apply a `Content-Security-Policy` at the `meta` tag of a Vue + Quasar application.

The meta tag looks like:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'none';" />`

And now I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Refused to compile or instantiate WebAssembly module because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive:
```

This application is built with Quasar (`"quasar": "1.20.1"`) and has the following dependencies (`"vue": "2.6.14"`, `"vue-loader": "15.9.7"` and `"webpack": "4.44.2"`). The `WebAssembly.instantiate()` seems to come from Webpack...so my question is, how do I disable it? (at least for the production build, because I get this error both in dev and prod mode).

I really wish to avoid applying an `unsafe-eval` directive to my CSP. There is this other one `wasm-unsafe-eval` which will work (it will prevent the error), but I'm unsure if it's safe to be used. Any help in that sense is appreciated.